# xml xpath expression needed in matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, xpath, xml-parsing

Following is part of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<osm generator="osmfilter 1.3A" version="0.6">
<node id="21295457" lat="53.4848139" lon="9.1540558" />
<node id="21316767" lat="53.0771599" lon="8.8030142" >
    <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="crossing"/>
    <tag k="crossing" v="traffic_signals"/>
</node>
<node id="254069931" lat="48.9309975" lon="8.63482" >
    <tag k="name" v="KV Ersingen Kirchbergsiedlung"/>
    <tag k="power" v="substation"/>
</node>
<node id="254070051" lat="48.9277761" lon="8.6328671" >
    <tag k="name" v="Umspannstation Ersingen Laierbergstraße"/>
    <tag k="power" v="sub_station"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="EnBW"/>
</node>
<node id="21929724" lat="54.8040971" lon="9.4346464" />
<node id="3444576256" lat="49.3993194" lon="11.0195838" >
    <tag k="power" v="station"/>
</node>
<node id="3444576257" lat="49.4002323" lon="11.0183178" >
    <tag k="power" v="station"/>
</node>
```

I would like to get the attribute `id` of each node by running a loop and then checking if that node has childnodes `tag`

This i have achieved using the following code

```
xDoc = xmlread(path);
osmNode = xDoc.getDocumentElement;
nodes = osmNode.getElementsByTagName('node');
node_Matrix = zeros(nodes.getLength,3);
for i = 0 : nodes.getLength-1
    node_IDs = nodes.item(i).getAttribute('id');
    node_Matrix(i+1,1) = str2double(node_IDs);

    if nodes.item(i).hasChildNodes
        import javax.xml.xpath.*
        factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        xpath = factory.newXPath();
        expression = xpath.compile('//osm/node[i][tag[@v="station"] or tag[@v= "substation"] or tag[@v="sub_station"]]');
        List = expression.evaluate(xDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        List.getLength;
    end
end
```

Now, I would like to check if the the childnodes `tag` of each node has an attribute `v="substation` or `v="sub_station` or `v="station` without looping through all childnodes. For this i used the xpath concept. But, I need an xpath expression which does not give me all the matches but just the match(if present) inside the present loop iteration `i`

I have included the part `node[i]` in my xpath expression `//osm/node[i][tag[@v="station"] or tag[@v= "substation"] or tag[@v="sub_station"]]`
But this gives me all the matches. 
What am i missing here? Could some one please give me the right expression?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using XPath that relative to current `nodes.item(i)` instead, for example :

```java
.....
expression = xpath.compile('self::*[tag[@v="station"] or tag[@v= "substation"] or tag[@v="sub_station"]]');
List = expression.evaluate(nodes.item(i), XPathConstants.NODESET);
List.getLength;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. Could you give me some links(apart from w3schools.com!) where i can read up on keywords like `self` etc. I am pretty new to xml, xpath and would like to learn more!

Comment: Surely I'd recommend the official [XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for reference